# Call VB function from javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a javascript in my asp file where I would like to call a vb function from.

Asp javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function functionName(sender, args) {
        var variable = args.get_value();
        PageMethods.VBFunctionName(variable);
    }
</script>
```

Function in VB:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function VBFunctionName(variable As String) As String
    Dim result As String = variable
    Return result.ToString()
End Function
```

And, I have also added the ScriptManager to enable page methods:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

But, It is not working! In the asp file, when I type 'PageMethods' the autocomplete for this option it's not available. So, I think the error is with the EnablePageMethods.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you getting any error message when u run the app?

Comment: No errors, but the line " PageMethods.VBFunctionName(variable); " does not call the Function. When I start typing PageMet... and try a CTRL + space to select the PageMethods function, the function it's not available.

Comment: is there any error method in your browser's console? And did you include the ScriptManager tag in the page _before_ your javascript function?

Comment: No errors in the browser's console and yes, I have included the ScriptManager tag before the js function..

Comment: How are you calling `functionName`? Are you in an aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are making an *Ajax* call but not setting any *callback* to read the response from the server. You need to define a callback function (and optionally a failure function) to set what you are going to do with the response.

So your `script` tag should look like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function functionName(sender, args) {
        var variable = args.get_value();
        PageMethods.VBFunctionName(variable,onSuccess); //pass callback function
    }
    function onSuccess(response) {
        alert(response); //Do whatever you wanna do with response.
    }
</script>
```

Also, since we are working inside javascript script tag, I don't think Visual Studio will be able to suggest u the server methods.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using JQuery to call VB Function from javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function functionName(sender, args) {
      var variable = args.get_value();

      $.get( "@Url.Action("VBFunctionName")?variable=" + variable, function( data ) {
         alert(data);
      });
   }
</script>
```